# Calculate date from calendar week, weekday and year in powershell

Tags: date, powershell, iso8601

How to calculate a date from ISO 8601 calendar week, weekday and year in powershell?

Example: calendar week 3, weekday 4, year 2017 should return a date object 1/19/2017

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please show what you have tried and where you have failed, thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculating_a_date_given_the_year.2C_week_number_and_weekday has the formula for doing this. You need to be aware that the .NET enumeration for `System.DayOfWeek` ranges from 0 to 6 (Sunday to Saturday) rather than the ISO definition of 1 to 7 (Monday to Sunday).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the module [IsoDates.psm1 by Joel Bennett](http://poshcode.org/966)
It's as easy as:

```
## Q:\Test\2017\01\19\SO_41743960.ps1
Import-Module 'Q:\test\posh\IsoDates.psm1'

"IsoDayofWeek for {0:D} is {1} vs {2}" -f `
      (Get-Date "01/15/2017"),
      (Get-ISODayOfWeek "01/15/2017"),
      ((Get-Date "01/15/2017").DayOfweek.value__)
"ISODateString for today is {0}" -F (Get-ISODateString)
"ConvertFrom-ISODateString {0} is {1:D}" -f "2017-W01-1",
      (ConvertFrom-ISODateString("2017-W01-1"))
```

Returning this output (on my German locale pc):

```
IsoDayofWeek for Sonntag, 15. Januar 2017 is 7 vs 0
ISODateString for today is 2017-W03-4
ConvertFrom-ISODateString 2017-W01-1 is Montag, 2. Januar 2017
```